# HA master cluster: How to get the right version of apiserver

Tags: kubernetes

I'm currently trying to configure a highly available master cluster. 
I followed the [proper documentation](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/admin/high-availability.html) but i'm facing the following issue.
My kubectl version is v1.1.2

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.2", GitCommit:"3085895b8a70a3d985e9320a098e74f545546171", GitTreeState:"clean"}
error: Failed to negotiate an api version. Server supports: map[v1beta1:{} v1beta2:{} v1beta3:{}]. Client supports: [v1 extensions/v1beta1].
```

And my apiserver doesn't match the same version:

```
curl -ku kube:changeme https://10.115.99.31/version
{
  "major": "0",
  "minor": "18+",
  "gitVersion": "v0.18.0-71-g0bb78fe6c53ce3-dirty",
  "gitCommit": "0bb78fe6c53ce38198cc3805c78308cdd4805ac8",
  "gitTreeState": "dirty"
}
```

I didn't find a way to list the tags for the kube-apiserver docker images from the google repository.
How can i do that please ?

Regards,
Smana

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the documentation has an out-of-date kube-apiserver.yaml file. I ran into this issue with another deployment guide. You should file this as a bug on [their github page](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues).

The image for the api server

```
gcr.io/google_containers/kube-apiserver:9680e782e08a1a1c94c656190011bd02
```

is at v0.18.0 from several months ago.

you will need to replace the "image" line in kube-apiserver.yaml on each machine with the current image. I'm not sure what the current image is. But ill keep digging.